# How to pass generics to an Spring CRUD Repository's save method

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-data

Let's say we have three JPA objects with name and id. I made an interface with getters+setters for name and id.

```
class Car implements MetadataObject
class Bus implements MetadataObject
class Train implements MetadataObject
```

We also have three repositories for these JPA objects:

```
interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long>
interface BusRepository extends CrudRepository<Bus, Long>
interface TrainRepository extends CrudRepository<Train, Long>
```

For each of these objects we want to run the same method in an spring service. (highly simplified)

```
private void importMetadata(CrudRepository<? extends MetadataObject, String> mRepository) {
    Optional<? extends MetadataObject> currentOptional = mRepository.findById(1);

    if (currentOptional.isPresent()) {
        MetadataObject current = (MetadataObject) currentOptional.get();
        current.setName("a1");
        mRepository.save(current);
    }
}
```

Which is callable by the same spring service by

```
@Autowired
private CarRepository carRepository;
...
importMetadata(carRepository);
```

This results in the error:

```
The method save(S) in the type CrudRepository<capture#4-of ? extends MetadataObject, Long> is not applicable for the arguments (MetadataObject)
```

Which is odd if I look at Springs CRUD Repository: `CrudRepository<T, ID>` and its save method: `<S extends T> S save(S entity);`.

In our example we have `T = ? extends MetadataObject` and `S = ? extends ? extends MetadataObjects`.

If we change my function to `private void importMetadata(CrudRepository<MetadataObject, String> bdbRepository)` the save method is correct but I can't call the method with my carRepository anymore

```
The method importMetadata(CrudRepository<MetadataObject,String>) in the type <...> is not applicable for the arguments (CarRepository)
```

Be aware: I highly simplified the example. I know that in this example Interfaces for these JPA classes makes no sense. I also know that my method makes no sense but it highlights the problem perfectly.

My question would be: What to pass to save or how to rewrite this function that it works? What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: So the `importMetadata` method is within the `MetadataObject` object? Or is it present in each specific object `CarRepository` etc.?

Comment: With the line `CrudRepository<? extends MetadataObject, String>` you basically say, that the first generic type is just of `MetadataObject`. If you "translate" it to class casting, it would be like `MetadataObject myObject = (MetadataObject)myCar`. So you work wth a `MetadataObject` type, despite it's a `Car` type. I _think_ this is, what the template does not like. But i'm not 100% sure.

Comment: The importMetadata method is seperate from the repository / jpa in an service class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method definition:

```
private void <T extends MetadataObject>importMetadata(CrudRepository<T, String> mRepository) {
   Optional<T> currentOptional = mRepository.findById(1);

   if (currentOptional.isPresent()) {
       T current = currentOptional.get();
       current.setName("a1");
       mRepository.save(current);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually came to the same conclusion. But this does not answer my question on WHY the above does not work. It reads exactly the same ...

Comment: Because it unable to prove that `save` consume exactly same type that `findOne` produce. All `?` types are different.

Comment: strictly speaking `mRepository.save(current)` fails because `mRepository` here may be `Car` repository while `current` is in fact `Bus`. Using explicit type `T` help to prove that this is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I will try the explain the reason the method `save` of `CrudRepository<? extends MetadataObject, String> mRepository` fails.

Suppose we have a generic class:

```
class C<T> {
public void save (T t) {
// .. whatever
}
}
```

When we write something like:

```
void f (C<? extends Object> c) {
    c.save(new Object());
}
```

the compiler complains about the `c.save` line.

That's because, when applying the type restriction, the compile doesn't know whether the `c` reference points, in fact, to `C<Object>` or `C<Number>` or whatever, since both `C<Object>` and `C<Number>` are accepted as arguments for `f`.

Because of that, the compiler doesn't know whether the `save` method's argument is allowed or not, hence the error.